# Find the maximum weight edge in a graph G?

Tags: algorithm, graph

My assignment is like, given V villages that connected with E roads in graph G, every road is labeled with a positive number. And you have to at least at the level of this number to access this road. In other word, if a road labeled 5, then your level has to be at least 5 or more to access this road. Now my assignment ask to design annalgorith, find the minimum level of clearance needed to be able to reach any of the villages in V from any other. So, my interpretation is we can just find the maximum weight edge in a graph. But I haven’t figure out what algorithm is appropriate for this condition.

Comment: @mangusta If the graph has vertices A,B,C and edges (AB,1), (BC,1) and (AC,1.5), then a level 1 can travel everywhere using the edges (AB) and (BC), but the shortest path from A to C gives maximum weight 1.5.

Comment: @conditionalMethod, thanks for pointing that out! you're right

Comment: You can sort the edges from smallest weight to largest. Start with just the set of vertices of the graph and no edges. Start adding the edges to the graph in the previous order. Keep adding edges while the graph is not connected or you run out of edges. The weight of the last edge added gives you the solution.

Comment: For testing connectedness: When you add the first edge mark both vertices that it joins. As you add new edges mark any new vertices that can be reached using the new edge. As long as there are vertices not marked, the graph is still not connected.

Comment: That's basically the way Kruskal's minimum spanning tree algorithm works) in simple words we need to pick the largest edge of the minimum spanning tree

Comment: @mangusta Good to know the name. I am not really a programmer, so I have many basic gaps in my knowledge.

Comment: @mangusta You are correct but actually you can look for the largest edge of the [`MBST`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bottleneck_spanning_tree) instead and it will take `O(E)` and not `O(E log V)`.

Comment: @Yonlif wow that MBST thing is something new for me, thanks for mentioning it

Comment: @mangusta No problem, notice that every MST is MBST so your solution is still correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in `O(E)`.

Why your solution is wrong? Consider a triangle where two edges are 1 and the last is 2, the lowest clearance needed is 1, your solution says 2.

The solution I can think of is to create the [Minimum bottleneck spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bottleneck_spanning_tree) (MBST), than take it's maximal edge, and this will be your clearance level.

Why will it work? Well this tree's greatest edge is the smallest you can get (Minimum bottleneck) and still reach everywhere in the graph (spanning).

`MBST` can be [created in `O(E)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bottleneck_spanning_tree#Camerini's_algorithm_for_undirected_graphs) using divide and conquer methods, than passing over all of the edges in that tree to find the max is `O(E)`. In total `O(E)`.

You can solve it using a simple [`MST`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree), since any `MST` is `MBST` ([proof in q3](https://stanford.edu/~rezab/discrete/Midterm/midterm2016_soln.pdf)), but this will take `O(E log V)` or `O(E + V log V)`, depending on the algorithm ([Kruskal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) or [Prim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm)).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but why mention to use MBST instead of MST(since every MST must is MBST), it's just faster? I prefer one of the command said we can use Kruskal's algorithm to find the MST in the graph. Because my lecture just covered the  Kruskal's algorithm and divide and conquer methods.

Comment: @D.dream Yes, it's just faster, ask your professor what is the time complexity you need to reach. When I did in my university Algo1 we had this in our homework and this is what I answered.

Comment: @D.dream I edited it, if you are satisfied with the answer I would appreciate if you will approve it.